# Arduino UNO(master read) + NANO(slave write) i2c buttons+stepper

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, button, stepper

First of all, I'm new to arduino. Check the EDIT line below the two codes.

I have connected motor shield to arduino uno. Connection between the two arduinos are A5 to A5, A4 to A4, 5V to 5V and GND to GND. I have a stepper connected to UNO, and a button connected to nano.

**EDIT5:** *I deleted the messy previous codes, the question was answered.*
However, I cant get the steppers to rotate(they only vibrate). Any advice is appreciated. The code right now is:

Master

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <AFMotor.h>
//define steppers
AF_Stepper motor1(48, 1); 
AF_Stepper motor2(48, 2);

//define variables
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(5); //begin i2c communication
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  motor1.setSpeed(10);  // 10 rpm   
  motor2.setSpeed(10);  // 10 rpm 

  motor1.release();
  motor2.release();
  delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(500); // wait 0.5 second 
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
    //read x,y from slave
    x = Wire.read();
    y = Wire.read();

    if (x == 1) //stepper1 rotate forward
    {  
      motor1.step(100, FORWARD, SINGLE); 
    }
    else if (x == 2) //stepper1 rotate backward
    {
      motor1.step(100, BACKWARD, SINGLE); 
    }
     else if (y == 1) //stepper2 rotate forward
    {
      motor2.step(100, BACKWARD, SINGLE);
    }
     else if (y == 2) //stepper2 rotate backward
    {
      motor2.step(100, BACKWARD, SINGLE);
    }
}
```

Slave

```
#include <Wire.h>

//define buttons
const int button1 = 2; 
const int button2 = 3;
const int button3 = 4;
const int button4 = 5;

//define state of buttons
int buttonState1 = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;
int buttonState3 = 0;
int buttonState4 = 0;

//define variables
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

void setup()
{
   //start i2c communication
   Wire.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  //read state of buttons
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(button1);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(button2);
  buttonState3 = digitalRead(button3);
  buttonState4 = digitalRead(button4);

    //if button1 is pressed,send x to master
    if(buttonState1 == HIGH){
      x = 1;
      Wire.beginTransmission(5);
      Wire.write(x);
      Wire.endTransmission();
    }
    //if button2 is pressed,send x to master
    else if(buttonState2 == HIGH)
    {
      x = 2;
      Wire.beginTransmission(5);
      Wire.write(x);
      Wire.endTransmission();
    }
    //if button3 is pressed,send y to master
    if(buttonState3 == HIGH){
      y = 1;
      Wire.beginTransmission(5);
      Wire.write(y);
      Wire.endTransmission();
    }
    //if button4 is pressed,send y to master
    else if(buttonState4 == HIGH)
    {
      y = 2;
      Wire.beginTransmission(5);
      Wire.write(y);
      Wire.endTransmission();
    }
}
```

Comment: slave uses onReceive. your "Slave" code is master code

Comment: @Juraj Yeah, I realised it. Don't you know how is it possible to make it work ?

Comment: @RóbertPollák What did you realise? If you realised, can't you fix it? In any case Arduino has [a tutorial for when you want to transfer data from the slave to the master](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader)

Comment: @frarugi87 That tutorial is great, I followed the steps and worked. However, the problem was when I wanted to create what I wrote above. Button to control the stepper.

Comment: Well, instead of sending "hello" you have to send the button status. From the other part, instead of printing it you have to use it properly. Try modifying first the servo to send you '0' or '1' and the master prints it on the serial, then when it works modify the master to interprete it as a command. If you have problems (but I think you won't, since you already did it) you can ask showing what you did in the meantime

Comment: I see a lot of bugs everywhere, but I am totally confused which code that you are going to use. First decide which Arduino board should be the master and which one the slave. A master can send data to a slave or request data from a slave.

Comment: @Jot I was told not to delete the previous codes, so I just make an edit. My uno is the master reader, nano is the slave writer. I think I almost figured it out, I'm just stuck at a point, where if I write a char I predefined, the stepper turns on, but I can't make it run with the button.

Comment: About "edit 3", the slave at address 8 and the master polls the slave via i2c. That is okay. The master can request two bytes and read two bytes (for example as HIGH or LOW) and omit the Wire.available. The slave should always write two bytes, just write 'buttonState1' and 'buttonState2'. No if-statement needed.

Comment: I have an important question: are you using an extra Arduino board because there are not enough pins available for two buttons? Please don't do that. First of all, you should buy a better driver board. Second, all the analog pins of the Arduino board are digital pins as well. If you have no servo motor connected to the shield, pin 9 and 10 can be used as well. There is also pin 2 and 13 which are not used. That means with that shield you have still 10 pins for buttons! (or 8 when using  two servo motors).

Comment: @Jot is there a way we can send DMs instead of commenting? It would make this thing faster.
Anyways, yes I use another board because not only there are not enough pins for the buttons, but I want to add bluetooth module.

Comment: There is a chat (never used it), but so far this is all about Arduino and meaningful.

Comment: Could we somehow set up that chat?
I couldn't figure it out how to set up the buttons with analog pins. My code is there, I updated my code, could you help me with that, so I wouldn't need to use I2C so far.

Comment: To use an analog pin as a digital pin, use the name of the pin: pinMode(A0, INPUT), digitalRead(A0), and so on. Or in your sketch, for example: const int button4 = A0; You are receiving two bytes via i2c, so you must send two bytes. If that is not what you want, then you have to forgot about programming code and first define the data that will be transmitted via i2c. Describe the protocol of the data. I'm kind of lost, since you are trying many things without a direction to go to. Don't forget to use @Jot, or else I won't be notified.

Comment: By the way, how you know which motor shield do I have? I use two steppers so I might be able to do that without i2c, but I want to use bluetooth module to control the steppers wirelessly. @Jot

Comment: A little guessing and the "AFMotor.h" give it away. The newer Adafruit Motor Shield uses a different name, so this must be the old one. If you are planning to use SoftwareSerial together with i2c, then you get into new problems. The i2c needs interrupts to run smooth, and the SoftwareSerial takes over the Arduino to do its work.

Comment: Well, I've got [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/81). Could I use any newer library? I just want to connect a bluetooth module(dont know which one yet) to nano(slave) to control the steppers. By the way, the 9V battery wasn't new, I'm going to buy one right now, I'll be back soon and tell you if that was the problem. @Jot

Comment: @Jot The new battery still won't rotate just vibrate. I guess the problem would be somewhere else I can't locate.

Comment: The thing is, its rotating without i2c, but only vibrates with. @Jot

Comment: A 9V battery is for smoke detectors, you can not use it with an Arduino board and certainly not for motors. That old motor driver needs that old library, and the new motor driver module has its own library. The bluetooth works best with a hardware serial port. You are running so fast into every possible problem, is there someone who can help you at your place?

Comment: @Jot not really that's the problem. Why is this a thing that without i2c its working correctly, with i2c, its not. That's why I wanted to get into chat with you somehow if you have time for that.

Comment: You might request to delete this question and start a new one. Tell what your goal is and ask how to achieve that, and tell what hardware you already have. This website is for questions and answers, perhaps forum.arduino.cc is a better place.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do! @Jot thanks everything once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The master could be the central unit which makes all the decisions, or the slave could preprocess the information.

It is best to start with a single byte to make it work. But I have made examples for two bytes anyway.

The next examples requests two buttons via i2c. You can change the HIGH and LOW into an integer value, but this is a start to make it work.

**Master (without checking)**

```
void loop()
{
  Wire.requestFrom(8,2);    // request 2 bytes from slave device #8
  int button1 = Wire.read();
  int button2 = Wire.read();

  Serial.print("button1=");
  Serial.println(button1 == HIGH ? "HIGH" : "LOW");

  Serial.print("button2=");
  Serial.println(button2 == HIGH ? "HIGH" : "LOW");

  // Some delay is needed, to prevent a 100% i2c bus load.
  // Perhaps 1 ms is enough, now 500 ms for testing.
  delay(500);
}
```

**Master (with checking)**

```
void loop()
{
  Wire.requestFrom(8,2);    // request 2 bytes from slave device #8
  if(Wire.available() == 2)   // are 2 bytes received ?
  {
    int button1 = Wire.read();
    int button2 = Wire.read();

    Serial.print("button1=");
    Serial.println(button1 == HIGH ? "HIGH" : "LOW");

    Serial.print("button2=");
    Serial.println(button2 == HIGH ? "HIGH" : "LOW");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("The slave was not found");
  }

  // Some delay is needed, to prevent a 100% i2c bus load.
  // Perhaps 1 ms is enough, now 500 ms for testing.
  delay(500);
}
```

**Slave (very simple)**

```
void requestEvent()
{
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(button1);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(button2);
  Wire.write( (byte) buttonState1);
  Wire.write( (byte) buttonState2);
}
```

**Slave (advanced, update button state in the loop)**

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int button1Pin = 2;
const int button2Pin = 3;

// Variables that are used in a interrupt and also outside
// that interrupt must be declared as volatile.
// Then the compiler knows that they can change at any moment.
volatile byte buttonState1;
volatile byte buttonState2;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(button1Pin,INPUT);
  pinMode(button2Pin,INPUT);
  Wire.begin(8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // register event
}

void loop()
{
  // keep the variables updated with the latest information.
  buttonState1 = (byte) digitalRead(button1Pin);
  buttonState2 = (byte) digitalRead(button2Pin);
}

// function that executes whenever data is requested by master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void requestEvent()
{
  // send the two bytes.
  Wire.write(buttonState1);
  Wire.write(buttonState2);
}
```

Comment: Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks", but still, thank you @Jot.
Anyways, I managed to write a code that's running, but the steppers are just vibrating, not rotating. Any solution for it?

Comment: That is an other problem. Try to make a small test sketch (without using the i2c bus and the other board) to test it. It means there not enough power or the wrong driver or electrical noise that backfires into the arduino board. You know that the motor shield that you are using is the worst, cheapest, weakest motor shield there is? It can drive only a very, very, very small toy motor. Maybe not even that.

Comment: When I used it without i2c bus, only with the shield and one button(because only pin D2 is free on that shield and analog pins) it was working okay, but now, with this setup, its not working.

Comment: You could add a check in the receiveEvent if the howMany == 1. Since a single byte is expected it should be 1. Calling the motor.step from an interrupt function might cause problems. If possible, you should do such things in the Arduino loop(). Don't fill the i2c bus with 100% load. Add a delay in the master Arduino. Start at least with 100 ms. Work cleaner! with the code and explanation. You have now called the master the slave and the other way around.